# Using Sugar ORM with UUID or Joda-Time

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jodatime, sugarorm

I'm creating a mobile application that will have users as defined below:

```
public class UserObject extends SugarRecord<UserObject>
{
    public UUID Id;
    public String Name;
    public int DefaultSort;
    public String Username;
    public Date LastLogin;

    public UserObject()
    {

    }

    public UserObject(UUID id, String name, int defaultSort, String username, String password, Date lastLogin)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.DefaultSort = defaultSort;
        this.Username = username;
        this.LastLogin = lastLogin;
    }
}
```

These users will be retrieved from an API - the IDs are stored in the Database as uniqueidentifiers (or GUIDs in C#).

When I enter a new record into the users table, everything works just fine:

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    UUID newUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    UserObject newUser = new UserObject(newUID, "David", 1, "userOne", "password", dt.toDate());
    newUser.save();
```

However, when I try and retrieve the value back out I get an error:

> Class cannot be read from Sqlite3 database. Please check the type of field Id(java.util.UUID)

Does Sugar ORM (or SQLite) simply not support UUIDs? If I try with the Joda DateTime, replacing the "LastLogin", the table just won't build at all so it looks as if it can create the fields, just not retrieve/store them...

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem? I'm ghaving the same issue. I'd like to use Joda Localtime objects in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use var with name `Id`. Sugar record uses `Id` to store index values.  Use anything except `Id`

```
public class UserObject extends SugarRecord{
    public UUID uId;
    public String Name;
    public int DefaultSort;
    public String Username;
    public Date LastLogin;

    public UserObject()
    {

    }

    public UserObject(UUID uId, String name, int defaultSort, String username, String password, Date lastLogin)
    {
        this.uId= uId;
        this.Name = name;
        this.DefaultSort = defaultSort;
        this.Username = username;
        this.LastLogin = lastLogin;
    }
}
```

from the v1.4 it is no longer need to use SugarRecord

Answer (score 0):

Sugar ORM won't be able to build the date object again when retrieving data from the database. If you take a look at your database, it's probably storing strings (that's the case with me, and I'm using JODA).

In my case I overcame this issue by using strings instead of data objects. You will have to parse them after you retrieve the data from the database, but I believe that's the only option you have, since [SQLite only support a few data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).